# Drupal 5 CCK fields are not being displayed in node

Tags: drupal, cck

I have a Drupal 5.1 site. I installed cck module version cck 5.x-1.8. Then went to modules and activated all checkboxes : content, etc. Then created a new Content Type, Added a new field, text integer for age. Then went ahead and created new content, named say news. The new cck field displayed when editing, but when I go to the created node, only the title and body show up, the new field: age does not appear. The age should be displayed with the title and body but it doesn't. In the database I see the table content_type_news_content has the value I entered.

shows editing
[image: sale]

doesn't show view 
[image: nosale]

Comment: You'll do well to find anyone on here who remembers Drupal 5, might I suggest you flag for a moderator to migrate your question to drupal.stackexchange.com where it will get more exposure?

Comment: Why are you using d5 if it's a new website? Have you checked permissions on viewing of that cck field?